# SQL join one table to other table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this sql for getting data by joining 3 tables , sample_register, villages and water_cssr.

```
SELECT
  sample_register.location,
  sample_register.description,
  villages.distance,
  case when water_cssr.istp='Cs' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as total_cs,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='Y'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as bdl_cs,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then min(water_cssr.activity) end as csmin,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then max(water_cssr.activity) end as csmax,
  case when water_cssr.istp='Sr' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as total_sr,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='Y'and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as bdl_sr,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='N' and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then min(water_cssr.activity) end as srmin,
  case when water_cssr.bdl='N' and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then max(water_cssr.activity) end as srmax
FROM sample_register
LEFT JOIN villages on sample_register.location=villages.location
LEFT JOIN sample_allocation on sample_register.usin=sample_allocation.usin
INNER JOIN water_cssr ON water_cssr.usin = sample_register.usin
GROUP BY sample_register.location, sample_register.description, sample_allocation.cs 
order by villages.dist_group, villages.location
```

I get a result like this

```
Location   Type    Distance   Total_cs   Bdl_cs   Csmin   csmax   Total_sr   Bdl_sr   Srmin   srmax
A          TYPE1   5                                               1         1
B          TYPE2   10         1          1        4       12
B          TYPE2   10                                              1         1        1       8
C          TYPE3   15                                              1         1        9       14
C          TYPE3   15         1          1        15      24
D          TYPE1   10                                              1         1
E          TYPE2   10         1          1
F          TYPE1   20         1          1
```

In the above location B and C has two rows each with one row has value in  4th to 7th columns and the other row has values in 8th to 11th columns. I want the content of these two rows in a single row since the valuses in 1st column to 3rd column is common for both rows. For example row two and three combined should produce a row like this

```
B   TYPE2   10  1   1   4   12  1   1   1   8
```

Please help me to restructure the SQL

Comment: Why are you grouping by all three of GROUP BY sample_register.location, sample_register.description, sample_allocation.cs ? Which one of these columns is causing rows 2 and 3 not to be aggregated?

Comment: sample_allocation.cs preventing aggregation

Comment: @Serpiton you r right. But my requirement is to get an aggregation on location and description and show the values of sr and cs in corresponding columns. At present values of cs and sr are in same column in water_cssr table with another column specifies the value is of cs or sr

Comment: I know this may be a bit off-topic, but could you tell us about the table relations? Which of the following statements are right, which are wrong? There can be many sample_register with the same location. There can be many villages with the same location. There can be many sample_register with the same usin. There can be many sample_allocation with the same usin. There can be many water_cssr with the same usin. There can be many sample_allocation with the same cs.

Comment: @Thosrsten kettner each row in sample_register is unique with USIN as primary key, and each usin has a location, description and many other attributes. Some of the USINs in sample_register has a record in sample_allocation where cs or sr or h3 columns has values. There will be only one entry for one USIN in sample allocation. Villages has rows in which location is the primary key. Location in the sample_register is joined with location in villages to get other attributes of location. water_cssr has rows for USINs and there can be any many water_cssr with same USIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two sub queries and joined it like this

```
 SELECT * FROM  (SELECT
sample_register.location,
sample_register.description,
villages.distance, villages.direction,
case when water_cssr.istp='Cs' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as total_cs,
case when water_cssr.bdl='Y'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as bdl_cs,
case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then min(water_cssr.activity) end as csmin,
case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Cs' then max(water_cssr.activity) end as csmax
FROM
sample_register LEFT JOIN villages on sample_register.location=villages.location LEFT JOIN sample_allocation on sample_register.usin=sample_allocation.usin INNER JOIN water_cssr ON water_cssr.usin = sample_register.usin
 WHERE mid(sample_register.usin,3,1)='N' and  sample_register.doc between '$start_date' and '$end_date' AND water_cssr.istp='Cs'  GROUP BY sample_register.location, sample_register.description, sample_allocation.cs order by villages.dist_group, villages.location) AS a left JOIN (SELECT
sample_register.location,
sample_register.description,
villages.distance, villages.direction,
case when water_cssr.istp='Sr' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as total_sr,
case when water_cssr.bdl='Y'and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then COUNT(water_cssr.usin) end as bdl_sr,
case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then min(water_cssr.activity) end as srmin,
case when water_cssr.bdl='N'and water_cssr.istp='Sr' then max(water_cssr.activity) end as srmax
FROM
sample_register LEFT JOIN villages on sample_register.location=villages.location LEFT JOIN sample_allocation on sample_register.usin=sample_allocation.usin INNER JOIN water_cssr ON water_cssr.usin = sample_register.usin
 WHERE mid(sample_register.usin,3,1)='N' and  sample_register.doc between '$start_date' and '$end_date' AND water_cssr.istp='Sr'  GROUP BY sample_register.location, sample_register.description, sample_allocation.cs order by villages.dist_group, villages.location) as b on a.location=b.location and a.description=b.description"
```

Answer (score 0):

this just a concept:

- Find which tables or tables join that return 2 rows for B and C.
- Create query for that tables or tables join, so it will return 1 row
  for b and c and other records.
- then modify your query to use the new query in the join, if correct b
  and c won't return 2 rows anymore.

good luck